# Richfaces inputNumberSpinner value not set

Tags: jsf, richfaces, spinner

I have a spinner where the user must select a year. When the page is loaded the default value for the spinner is the `minValue` on the screen, but in the backing-bean the value is null.

I need to render some info when the page is first loaded taking the default value (minValue) of the spinner.

How to do that?

Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like that

Since that you know that when the page is first loaded spinnerValue is null , you can render 
`h:panelGroup` (for example) based on that condition

```
<h:panelGroup id="renderMe" rendered="#{myBean.spinnerValue eq null}">
    some text...
</h:pamelGroup>
```

?

Comment: That's a good idea. By the way, can I just initialize the `spinnerValue` in the backing bean with some value so it is not null?

Comment: value="#{myBean.someInt}" isn't working? b.t.w atleast in primefaces you can use simple int (not Integer) and that way it will be zero at start (instead null)

Comment: Nope. I was thinking something like `private int s = 2011;` so when the object is created the first value in the backing bean is 2011.

Comment: Did you generated getter/setter for that s ? try with Integer instead of int too... anyway my first solution is working? (with ... eq null ... or if you are using a simple int try rendered="#{myBean.spinnerValue eq 0}")?

Comment: Getter/setter, yes I did. Yes that's working now, I didn't have time yesterday !! Thanks !!